# Constructing an object other than specified parameters NOT giving me errors

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I was going through a book called Programming Principles and Practices using C++ but found a strange behavior of class construction.
Suppose I have a class as follows:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x)
        : y { x } { }

private:
    int y;
};
```

and I have another class which has an instance of class Foo as its member object

```cpp
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(Foo x)
        : y { x } { }

private:
    Foo y;
};
```

When I do the following:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Bar obj_1 { Foo { 1 } };
    Bar obj_2 { 2021 }; // this doesn't give me error?

    return 0;
}
```

obj_1 was constructed as specified in the constructor, but obj_2 doesn't give me any error message and to me it seems it just *magically* works.
My intention of having a member of a class as an instance of another class was to force the constructor to take a class instance as its argument, but not an integer.

Why doesn't it give me incorrect type error?

Comment: The Magic: Compiler am smart. It needs a `Foo`, but it got an `int` and knows how to turn an `int` into a `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this implicit conversion by declaring the `Foo` constructor `explicit`

```
explicit Foo(int x) : y { x } { }
```

in `main` this would require the caller to change their `obj_2` instantiation to

```
Bar obj_2 { Foo{2021} };
```

Comment: Or Bar(int)=delete; to just prevent Bar construction from int.